# Import Apache POI in Intellij for JAVA

Tags: java, excel, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I am trying to use an Excel spreadsheet with java, I read that Apache POI looks like the best solution regarding my concerns...

I downloaded the latest stable version of POI 3.11 from http://poi.apache.org/download.html

After it, I tried to add it in my Intellij project with two ways :

1. File - Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies - add - POI
2. File - Project Structure - Libraries - add - POI

After that, I tried to import as it is specified in the documentation:

```
import org.apache.poi
```

But it does not work, I guess it is because I did not add the library properly.

Comment: Take a look at this question [how to add library .jar to intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: I assume that import statement is in fact incomplete and broke upon posting the code?

Comment: You should define "does not work"

Comment: @Gimby  Yes totally Intellij answers : Cannot resolve symbol 'apache'

Comment: @Sharpedge : Before wrote the question I tried with the post that you posted to me...

Comment: which `.jar` file are you importing ?? Are you sure you're importing the correct `jar` ?

Comment: I recorded all my changes, and reboot the system and now it works...

Comment: Should I close or delete the question ?

Comment: Take a look at this question [how to add library .jar to intellij properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) and make sure you're importing the right `.jar` Clean and Build your project and then try.