# can't find apache poi libraries

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i'm trying for the first time the apache poi library to manage Execel files. I follow this steps to import apache poi:  [Import Apache POI in Intellij for JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024502/import-apache-poi-in-intellij-for-java).
The code compile without error but when i run it give me this error messages:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
> at Test.main(Test.java:16)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> ... 1 more

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Huawei\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\src\\TEST.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Row row = itr.next();
                Iterator<Cell> celliterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(celliterator.hasNext()){
                    Cell cell = celliterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()){
                        case STRING:    //field that represents string cell type
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:    //field that represents number cell type
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("NOT NUMERIC AND NOT STRING");
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and use Maven or Gradle - you will save loads of time and do not have to chase dependencies and dependencies of dependencies and dependencies of dependencies of dependencies to get your project to work...

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a classic Maven Project with a `.jar` downloaded not installed via `mvn` command.

If `ClassNotFoundException` raises in runtime, its because your project can't find the library after compiled.

Is this the case? If so, you must add the `.jar` via `mvn install` and declare him in your pom.xml. A better solution it's just adding the maven dependency directly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the example code needs poi-ooxml jar too - XSSFWorkbook is in poi-ooxml

Comment: It's not a Maven Project cause i created it as Java Application , so..i don't have pom.xml . I added the poi's .jar like "External Librarys" and appear in the correct section of the folder's project.

Comment: poi-ooxml.jar is one of the libreries.

Comment: Maven will save you a lot of trouble with libraries, but if you really want to stick with jars, try PJ Fanning solution.